# Tap on event inside List-View

Tags: android, listview, nativescript

i'm using a list-view in my nativescript project, and i want to handle the tap event on a specific object inside the list-view.
Let's assume we have this xml:

```
<ListView items="{{ friends }}">
    <ListView.itemTemplate>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label id="lbl_0" text="Say Hello!"/>
            <Label id="lbl_1" text="Say Goodbye!"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </ListView.itemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Now, if i want for each item in my list, to activate a handler for the tap on lbl_0 and a different handler for lbl_1, how can i tell to my list-view to do this.
I've tryed this code:

```
listView.on(listViewModule.ListView.itemTapEvent, function (args: listViewModule.ItemEventData) {
    var tappedItemIndex = args.index;
    var tappedItemView = args.view;
    // Do someting
});
```

but tappedItemView contains the stacklayout object not the label on which i clicked.
Anyone know how to set this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set `tap event` separately for each labels, also applied for other UI component (e.g button):

```
<ListView items="{{ friends }}">
    <ListView.itemTemplate>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label id="lbl_0" text="Say Hello!" tap="sayHello"/>
            <Label id="lbl_1" text="Say Goodbye!" tap="sayGoodbye"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </ListView.itemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Then in js file:

```
function sayHello(args) {
    // Your code
}
exports.sayHello = sayHello;
```

Or ts:

```
export function sayHello(args) { 
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, is working perfectly. Last question, i have a view-model file with all the functions, how can i call the sayHello function inside the view-model? Thank you

Comment: You're welcome, if my answer solves your problem, please mark the question answered so that others will know. About your second question, I don't understand your idea, could you please explain it more clearly or create another question? Y

Comment: The fact, is that when i use the itemTap property of the listview, i get in the ars the index of item tapped, but using this method with the tap in the label, how can i get the index of the item where the label is tapped.

Comment: You can get the object that bind into the label, which is `args.object.bindingContext`. That object is an element of your item list array, which is `friends`, so that you can use `indexOf` to find the index of that object in the array

Comment: var obj = args.object.bindingContext;
var index = friends.indexOf(obj);

Comment: Hi Dinh Le, thank you. I have another issue related to this. When using ios, if i click on the labels nothing happens, but if  i use the event itemTap is fired correctly, why?